# Ethereum Node. Не могу понять в чем заключается ошибка

Tags: ethereum

Пробовал ставить чистый geth клиент, синхронизация даже не проходила.
Попробовал lighthous, но, к сожалению как я понял он работает только "goerly". Но, может получится как-то сделать для mainnet? Не нашел ссылку синхронизации (параметр --checkpoint-sync-url)

Сейчас пробую создать клиент через geth init, но после инициализации и запуска все время получаю такую ошибку: Fatal: Failed to register the Ethereum service: ethash is only supported as a historical component of already merged networks

Мой genesis.json:

```
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 1,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0,
    "byzantiumBlock": 0,
    "constantinopleBlock": 0,
    "petersburgBlock": 0,
    "ethash": {}
  },
  "difficulty": "4",
  "gasLimit": "8000000",
  "alloc": {}
}
```

Помогите кто сможет(